# How to do a bar chart to org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'am new at using Scala and Spark and i'm trying to do a bar chart using org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.

I found that i can use scalaFX to do bar chart. The problem is that my task has to be done with jupyternotebook and when i try to import scalafx.application.JFXapp i get "error not found : value scalafx".
I'm using spylon-kernel. This is my data:

```
var numberOfAppsInCategory=df.select("Category").groupBy("Category").count().orderBy("count")
```

Can you help me to use scalafx in the spylon-kernel or use another way to do a bar plot to org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow some tutorials with [plotly](https://github.com/alexarchambault/plotly-scala) , or use [vegas](https://github.com/vegas-viz/Vegas#jupyter---scala) or use [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstart#breeze-viz)

Vegas is compatible with Spark. I used it with Apache Toree, I didn´t test with spylon-kernel. In Toree just import the dependence like

```
%AddDeps org.vegas-viz vegas_2.11 {vegas-version} --transitive
implicit val render = vegas.render.ShowHTML(kernel.display.content("text/html", _))
```

Comment: please ,can I use vegas to draw  AUC curve in scala?